# Count unique within combination of json keys in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery I do have a json stored in 1 column like this:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key3":"value3"}
{"key2": "value2"}
{"key3": "value3"}
```

What I'd want to know is how to calculate number of unique combinations, paying attention that there can be up to 100+ different keys so avoiding listing them would be beneficial.

In example above end result of unique number will be 2, because first and third matched by "key3", while second didn't matched with anything.

I understand how to build this with writing an app that will calculate it, but would like to see if there is any solution possible with 1 query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JSON values are formatted with no spaces after the `:`, then you can treat this as string manipulations:

```
with t as (
       select '{"key1":"value1", "key3":"value3"}' as kv union all
       select '{"key2":"value2"}' union all
       select '{"key3":"value3"}'
      )
select x, count(*)
from t cross join
     unnest(regexp_extract_all(t.kv, '"[^,]+"')) x
group by x
having count(*) = 1;
```

With the spaces, you can use `replace()` to get rid of them:

```
with t as (
       select '{"key1": "value1", "key3":"value3"}' as kv union all
       select '{"key2": "value2"}' union all
       select '{"key3": "value3"}'
      )
select replace(x, '": "', '":"'), count(*)
from t cross join
     unnest(regexp_extract_all(t.kv, '"[^,]+"')) x
group by 1
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but it almost doing what is needed :D Maybe I haven't described it well... so if we'll extend the json with another record like: 

{"key2": "value4", "key3":"value3"} 

end result would be:

"key1":"value1"
"key2":"value2"
"key2":"value4"

Where I'd like to have a number of 2 (the actual list of keys isn't required in my case, as I want to only know how many unique values are stored, and if 1 key/value is located in another record that also have additional keys, it still will be counted as 1 record) 

Hope it does make sense :D